# should i trim the roots of my phalaenopsis

Tags: indoors, orchids

i was recently repotting some orchids from the hardware store / ikea after watching https://www.youtube.com/MissOrchidGirl

some of the roots look like the one being held in the photo, where there is a substantial withered / dried part near the plant and further down the root it seems healthy(er). is the end of the root just growing in autonomy? should i cut it? does it actually still service the plant? many thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you get to any resolution? Did you perform any type of experiment or trial on this or any other plants?